# Duda con introduccion de datos por parte del usuario

Tags: c++

Estoy iniciandome en esto de la programación en C++ y he de decir que es uno de los pocos lenguajes de programación que de verdad me ha gustado.

Ahora estoy con el tema de introducción de datos por parte del usuario, pero me surge una duda, ya que en unos sitios veo que usan `"cin >> "` y en otros usan `cin.getline()`.

¿En qué se diferencian?

¿Cual es mejor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro de la programación orientada a objetos es habitual que los objetos dispongan de una serie de métodos que permiten interactuar con el objeto. Es el ejemplo de `cin.getline`.

Por otro lado, lenguajes como C++ admiten la sobrecarga de operadores. En algunos lenguajes como C, cada operador cumple una misión muy concreta y únicamente para tipos nativos (los predefinidos por el lenguaje) y su uso no se puede modificar bajo ninguna circunstancia. Sirva como ejemplo el operador suma:

```
int a = 5, b = 2;
int c = a + b; // correcto

struct test
{
  int valor;
};

struct test a,b;
a.valor = 5;
b.valor = 2;
struct test c = a + b; // ERROR, el compilador no sabe como aplicar este operando a una estructura
```

Como hemos dicho, en C++ es posible redefinir el comportamiento de ciertos operandos para adaptarlos a objetos particulares de nuestro programa. Así podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct test
{
  int valor;

  test& operator+(test& otro)
  {
    test toReturn;
    toReturn.valor = valor + otro.valor;
    return toReturn;
  }
};

struct test a, b;
a.valor = 3;
b.valor = 2;
struct c = a + b; // Correcto
std::cout << c.valor << '\n'; // Imprime 5
```

En la misma línea, otros operadores que se pueden sobrecargar son los de inserción `<<` y extracción `>>`:

```
struct test
{
  int valor;

  test& operator+(test& otro)
  {
    test toReturn;
    toReturn.valor = valor + otro.valor;
    return toReturn;
  }

  friend std::ostream&& operator<<(std::ostream& out, test& dato);
  friend std::istream&& operator>>(std::istream& in, test& dato);
};

std::ostream&& operator<<(std::ostream& out, test& dato)
{
  return out << dato.valor;
}

std::istream&& operator>>(std::istream& in, test& dato)
{
  return out >> dato.valor;
}

struct a;
std::cin >> a; // Se recibirá un entero y se almacenará en a.valor;
std::cout << a; // Se imprimirá el valor almacenado en a.valor;
```

No voy a entrar en detalles sobre el uso de `friend` porque eso me llevaría a tratar una serie de temas que exceden el ámbito de la pregunta.

Eso sí, sobrecargar operadores es algo a hacer únicamente en casos muy particulares para evitar comportamientos inesperados debidos a detallitos tontos del lenguaje como las conversiones implícitas.

Como detalle adicional, decir que los operadores se pueden invocar igual que cualquier otra función. Así podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct test a, b;
a.valor = 3;
b.valor = 2;
struct c = a.operator+(b); // Correcto
std::cout << c << '\n'; // Imprime 5
```

Así pues, el uso del operador `>>` viene determinado por una serie de sobrecargas de dicho operador, mientras que `cin.getline` no es más que una función miembro de `cin`.

Eso sí, a la hora de decidir qué opción usar presta mucha atención a los detalles de cada función. La librería estándar dispone de pocas opciones redundantes. Esto quiere decir que dos funciones pueden funcionar igual únicamente en apariencia.

Así, por ejemplo, `cin.getline` lee una cadena de texto hasta que se encuentra un salto de línea (o un caracter nulo), mientras que el operador `>>` se detiene al encontrar también un espacio.

Si, por ejemplo, por teclado se escribe `"Esto es una prueba"`:

- `cin.getline` recuperará `"Esto es una prueba"`
- `cin >> var` recuperará `"Esto"`

Esto sin contar con el hecho de que el operador `>>` permite recuperar enteros, números en coma flotante, ... mientras que `cin.getline` únicamente permite leer cadenas de texto.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He estado probando (porque no me gusta aceptar las cosas sin probarlas. Ojo, no dudo de tu palabra sinó que si no lo pruebo no lo retengo en la memoria) y con el comando cin >> me recupera el string entero. Es decir, si el usuario pone "Hola me llamo alberto", al hacer cout << nombrevariable me aparece todo el string.

Comment: @Jogofus `std::string cad; std::cin >> cad; std::cout << "\n#" << cad << "#\n";`. El código anterior te debería imprimir únicamente el texto que introduzcas hasta el primer espacio. Las almohadillas hacen las veces de marcador por si tienes más código en la función.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` puede "leer" (convertir, hacer casting en realidad) cualquier tipo de dato y guardarlo en una variable, en cambio `cin.getline` sólo guarda strings (espera `char*` como parámetro).

Para mostrar un ejemplo de en qué caso usarías cuál:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int numero;
  char cadena[11];

  cout << "Ingrese su edad: ";
  cin >> numero;
  cin.ignore(); // consumir Enter (\n)

  cout << "Ingrese su nombre: ";
  cin.getline(cadena, 10);

  cout << "Su nombre es: " << cadena << " Y su edad: " << numero;

  return 0;
}
```